# SELECT query to mysql and return object

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I'm new to PHP. I've created classes that represent my database tables (I come from a .Net entity framework background). I would like to run my SELECT statement and pass back a `User` object. All the examples I've found parse the returned data. Is there a way to just do something like this and have it pass back a `User` object:

```
$user = new user();

$user = $mysqli->query($query, MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT);

return $user;
```

or do I have to parse the result first?

Note: all the fields in the user class match the fields in the database
I.E. $user->UserName = [user].[UserName]

Comment: you mean you want to get them as objects? http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php

Comment: Hope you can go back to .NET asap, it's a better world! :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use PDO with "fetchobject":

```
$statement = $db->query($query);    
$user = $statement->fetchObject('User');
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchobject.php

or convert (cast) each "row" of data to User Object ([example function](http://pastebin.com/Fxn1HuPM))

or try a [ORM PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_object-relational_mapping_software#PHP) solution